# list group and sum by column

Tags: python, list

I have the following

```
    (Decimal('1.000'), Decimal('419.760000'), Decimal('4.197600000'), Decimal('423.957600000'))             
(Decimal('1.000'), Decimal('62.370000'), Decimal('0.623700000'), Decimal('62.993700000'))           
(Decimal('2.000'), Decimal('7.920000'), Decimal('0.079200000'), Decimal('7.999200000'))
```

And I'd like to group them by the first column and sum the other columns (sum grouped by the first column, summarized for each column separately)...but I don't know how to do that...

I'm new to python...any pointers?

Thanks,
BR

Comment: Are the three tuples meant to be in a list?

Comment: If the tuples are supposed to be in a list, please **update** the question to fix the syntax so the **are** in a list.  Also.  Don't add comments ("the first column...not altogether") to a question which you own.  Please **update** the question to contain all the information and delete the comment.

Comment: Don't apologize.  It doesn't help to add comments to a question you own.  Just fix the question and delete your comments.  Your "list" syntax in the question is still wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming those three tuples are items in a tuple or list `numbers`:

```
column_sums = [sum(items) for items in zip(*numbers)]
```

Rereading your question, I think you may instead mean you want to group all numbers except the first of each row by what the number in the first row is, and then get the sum of each group. If so, do it like this:

```
from collections import defaultdict

grouped = defaultdict(list)

for tpl in numbers:
    grouped[tpl[0]].extend(tpl[1:])

group_sums = dict((key, sum(lst)) for key, lst in grouped.items())
```

If you don't need the itermediate `grouped` variable, you may optimize like this:

```
group_sums = defaultdict(int)

for tpl in numbers:
    group_sums[tpl[0]] += sum(tpl[1:])
```

**Re: comment**

This would have been so much easier if you gave an example of the output you wanted in the first place. For example, you could have added this to your post:

> From the above example I want this output:
>
> ```
> {Decimal('1.000'): [
>    Decimal('482.130000'), Decimal('4.821300000'), Decimal('486.951300000')],
> Decimal('2.000'): [
>    Decimal('7.920000'), Decimal('0.079200000'), Decimal('7.999200000')]}
> ```

Then *I* could have posted this answer right away:

```
from itertools import izip_longest

group_sums = {}

for tpl in numbers:
    previous_sum = group_sums.get(tpl[0], [])
    iterator = izip_longest(previous_sum, tpl[1:], fillvalue=0)
    group_sums[tpl[0]] = [prev + num for prev, num in iterator]
```

This also works if the number of columns varies within a group. Please tell me I've understood the question correctly this time. :)

Comment: Hi, I'm trying it out but I ran into a problem... how can I display the sums in a for loop in django? if I do for var in group_sums and the {{ var }} I can display the first column... but I don't know how to access any other (sums). I've tried var.1, var[1],...

Comment: @Mission I see [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#std:templatetag-for) that you need to do `{% for key, value in data.items %}`, which then in our case becomes `{% for var, sum in group_sums.items %}`.

Comment: Thank you, I'm sorry but I forgot to mention in my original question... I need sums by the column... so grouped by the first column and then sums (including the grouped values) for each column separately.

Answer (score 0):

If the following input given:

```
inputData = [[1,2,3],
             [1,3,4],
             [5,6,7]]
```

And you expect to get grouped sum - e.g sum of first two(grouped by 1 from first col) rows and the third row itself(since there is no more rows with 5 within first column) then you may use the following code:

```
res = []
for i,val in enumerate(zip(*inputData )[0]):# first column
   filtered = filter(lambda x: x[0] == val, inputData)
   (not filtered in res and res.append(filtered))

print map(lambda comb: map(sum, zip(*comb)), res)
```

Comment: I get global name 'a' is not defined